# Conditionally change layout of the Columns with in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

i have grid with 3 columns and I have a few conditions,

1. on extra small device, columns will be stack at the top of each other
2. on small device, columns sizing will be 1:1:1
3. on medium device, columns sizing should be 2:2:8
4. on large device, again columns will be stack at the top of each other
5. on extra large device, again columns sizing will be 1:1:1

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 200px;">
        <div class="col-sm col-md-2 flex-lg-column col-xl bg-info"></div>
        <div class="col-sm col-md-2 flex-lg-column col-xl bg-light"></div>
        <div class="col-sm col-md-8 flex-lg-column col-xl bg-info"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now , What I have to do to stack column on large device. I thought flex-lg-column will do the trick, but no its keep showing medium device's sizing. Any idea? Any one?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check the .css file of bootstrap. I'm pretty sure it contains the class for extra-large devices as well. So in total, there are 4 classes based for 4 different size of devices.